# This command to rename all files fails: "find: 'rename': No such file or directory"

Tags: command-line, find, rename, batch-rename

Trying to replace all file names in a directory with `ai` to `newai`.

```
Execute: find . -exec rename 's/ai/newai/' {} ";"
Error: find: ‘rename’: No such file or directory
```

What could be the problem here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Use `mv` under linux to move a file to an optional new name

Comment: You may need to install the `rename` package